# Wordpress White Screen Error

Tags: php, errors, debug, wp-config

So I have encountered the white screen error of Wordpress.

I enabled the WP_DEBUG in the wp_config.php and found no errors. I also tried `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and it still didn't display any errors.

I have also tried increasing the memory limit of Wordpress, still no luck.

I read an article stating that a white screen error will appear if there are spaces before `<?php` and after `?>`. So I opened my files in my FTP and I found out that all the code in the files have double space in them. Even code from plugins have double space added to them.

What causes this? Is this because of my FTP and editor? I doubt because I have not encountered this yet.

Comment: Please set those settings to your `wp-config.php`: `define('WP_DEBUG',true); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); after few requests check the file in `wp-content/debug.log` and post results in your question.

Comment: That can be a bad settings for FTP transfer same as something wrong with Editing files. If you don't have anything that open you site as a project (Komodo/Textmate or other IDE) this not really possible... perhaps its a FTP transfer.

Comment: What do you mean by bad settings for FTP transfer? This is the first time I have encountered this problem..

Answer (score 0):

> What causes this?

It may be a [line ending problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). In *nix, the line ending is a single new line character. In windows it is a carriage return character followed by a new line character. [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) encoded files can also affect line endings.

Check your text editor documentation. There should be a way to convert DOS documents to UNIX documents and not transfer all those carriage returns to your web server.

I have seen it happen on client web sites. A theme file will have every other line blank. I usually run it through a search and replace (in my text editor) to change 2 consecutive line feeds into one and upload the file again.

> I read an article stating that a white screen error will appear if there are spaces before `<?php` and after `?>`

You can avoid the trailing space problem by removing the final `?>` from files you edit. I think this is recommended somewhere in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php). If your editor is capable, you can use search and replace across files to remove spaces at the top of PHP files. Just back them up first. :)